# Why is this function creating an infinite loop?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, loops

Why is this creating an infinite loop? And if it isn't creating one, why does the program freeze up? Not like IDLE stops responding, It just stops like I created a infinite loop and the only thing it does is input(). Try the code out to see what I mean. 
*(also, tell me if the for's are correct in the comments please)*

```
Accounts = {}
def create_account(x,y,z,a):
     global Accounts
     Checked = False
     while Checked == False:
        if x in Accounts:
            print("Sorry, that name has already been taken")
            print("Please choose a new name")
            x = input()
        for dictionary in Accounts:
            for key in dictionary:
                if a in key:
                    print("Sorry, password is invalid or not avalible")
                    print("Please choose a new password")
                    a = input()
     Accounts[x] = {"Proggress":y,"Points":z,"Pass":a}
     print(Accounts[x])
```

Comment: where does `Checked` become `True` to break the loop? Nowhere. Where is a `break` that might break it? Nowhere. No returns, no nothing, you'll get an infinite loop.

Comment: In order to exit the while loop, you have to set Checked to True

Comment: Why not `def create_account(name, progress, points, password)`? `x,y,z,a` is extremely unclear.

Comment: RIght, ok, Ill add that, but one thing that I should have made more clear, the print() is before the input(), and the print **never** outputs, so it doesn't get that far. I will add the Checked for sure, but i haven't gotten that far. And yes ian, it will be that way after testing is complete

Answer (score 1):

Your code creates an infinite loop because there is nothing to stop it.

`while checked == False` will do exactly what it sounds like, it will loop over the code over and over until `checked = True` OR until you `break`

`break` will simply stop the loop, allowing the program to finish.

`checked = True` will also stop the loop

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are trying to do is something like this:
This code is untested

```
Accounts = {}
def create_account(x,y,z,a):
     global Accounts
     Checked = False
     while Checked == False:
        if x in Accounts:
            print("Sorry, that name has already been taken")
            print("Please choose a new name")
            x = input()
        else:
            passwordOk = True
            for dictionary in Accounts:
                for key in dictionary:
                    if a in key:
                        passwordOk = False
                        break
                if not passwordOk:
                    break
            if not passwordOk:
                print("Sorry, password is invalid or not avalible")
                print("Please choose a new password")
                a = input()
            else:
                Checked = True # this is the important part that you missed
    Accounts[x] = {"Proggress":y,"Points":z,"Pass":a}
    print(Accounts[x])
```

Just for you to know, your code can be optimized. I tried to solve your issue by modifying as minimum code as possible, so that you could understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues causing this.

As you say,

> the print() is before the input(), and the print never outputs, so it doesn't get that far

However, let's take a step back:  the print statements are inside the block `if x in Accounts:`.  At the very first line, you set `Accounts` to be an empty dictionary (`Accounts = {}`), so no matter what `x` is, at that point, `x in Accounts` will never be true - there's *nothing* in it.

Now, you do have a line that adds items to `Accounts`:

```
Accounts[x] = {"Proggress":y,"Points":z,"Pass":a}
```

However, as other people have pointed out, you'll never get here - it's outside the loop, and the loop never exits because `Checked` is never set to `True`, nor is a `break` called.

Your program then is essentially just going through the same few steps that don't do anything:

1. Does `Checked == False`?  Yep, continue the loop.
2. Is `x in Accounts`?  Nope, skip this block.
3. For every `dictionary` in `Accounts`, do some stuff, but `Accounts` is empty, so I don't need to do anything.
4. Does `Check == False`?  Yep, continue the loop.

Comment: I know it says not to use comments for saying thanks, but thanks anyway, thats exactly what I needed. I forgot to add a pickle.dump statement after setting the accounts variable. Now I know I need to add something that will check if accounts is empty, then break. Thanks again!